# php & regexp - what is the number represent to

Tags: php, regex

I have a question in regexp -

```
$template = preg_replace("/\<\!\-\-\{(.+?)\}\-\-\>/s", "{\\1}", $template);
```

but I don't know what the '1' means, can anyone tell me about this? thanks all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply the first matching group of your regex (in this case, it's `(.+?)` which is inside `{}` in your regex), so that code replaces things like `<!--{test}-->` to `{test}`

as our good sir nomaD pointed in his comment below, it's better to use `$1` instead of `\\1` in your replacement string

```
$template = preg_replace("/\<\!\-\-\{(.+?)\}\-\-\>/s", "{$1}", $template);
                                                         ^^
                                                         this
```

Comment: Also it's recommended that you use $# instead of \\# to indicate group matches. e.g. `$template = preg_replace("/\<\!\-\-\{(.+?)\}\-\-\>/s", "{$1}", $template);` instead of `$template = preg_replace("/\<\!\-\-\{(.+?)\}\-\-\>/s", "{\\1}", $template);`

Comment: Thanks NiftyDude & nomaD, I think I know what it means.